# "We come through somebody" meaning

Tags: word-meaning

The book *Dynamics Of Life: Interplay of people, places and events* by Patricia Tuaweri says,

> Life is all about relationships. This is because it is not good for people to be alone. God made it in such a way that **everybody comes through somebody**. Not only do **we come through somebody**, we are also guided by somebody of some people.

what does "come through" mean here?

Comment: You'd better provide more context: name the source of the quote and cite a bigger chunk of text. This will make it easier for others to understand the meaning of the text and provide you with an answer.

Comment: It souns like a bad translation, especially the last part of the last senttence (we are also guided by somebody of some people), which is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've googled a bit and found out that the source of the text is "Dynamics of life: Interplay of people, places and events", by Patricia Tuaweri ([page link](https://books.google.ru/books?id=vYBPAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT27&ots=TymLVWZsVv&dq=%22Not%20only%20do%20we%20come%20through%20somebody%2C%20we%20are%20also%20guided%20by%20somebody%22&hl=ru&pg=PT27#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Within the larger context of the passage that includes your sentence, "come through somebody" means "born", or "come **into this life** through somebody".. Our existence begins "through somebody", that is, through our parents. But the things do not stop there, because we are then guided (brought up, educated, fostered etc.) by somebody.